# python regular expression capturing group usage '\.[8][x](large)'

Tags: python, regex

Let's say I have `BoxUsage:c4.8xlarge`  `BoxUsage:c4.1xlarge` or `BoxUsage:c4.100xlarge`  and I want to find a pattern that can detect all of them and replace "large" with "hello"

Desired result: `BoxUsage:c4.8xhello`

1.`re.sub('[a-z][0-9]\.[8][x](large)','hello',sentence)`

initial : "BoxUsage:c4.8xlarge"

output: "BoxUsage:hello"

2.`re.sub('\.[8][x](large)','hello',sentence)`

initial : "BoxUsage:c4.8xlarge"

output: "BoxUsage:c4hello"

I assume using `()` to capture groups, which means "hello" should replace the match inside the capturing group (here is "large"), however, it doesn't happen.

Can someone explain to me how capturing groups work and what is the proper way to replace "hello" with "large"?

Comment: What is the pattern that you are trying to catch? The way you explained, you should be using `replace(sentence,"8xlarge","8xhello")`.

Comment: I just want to solve this problem by using regext, I know I can use replace.

Comment: There must be a reason for using a wrong tool when a right tool is available.

Comment: I am practicing my regext skill at the moment. Said I want to match anything end with \.[0-9]*xlarge, how should I do that ?

Comment: Then you should read about the lookbehind assertion.

Comment: can you please show me how to do it. really appreciate it

Comment: Please read `regex` documentation. It's all there.

Comment: Here's a hint: you don't want to be capturing the substring you want to replace but rather the string you want to copy into the output.

Answer (score 0):

As others have commented, you're "over-thinking" the problem by trying to capture a substring. In all of the examples you've given, there is an unvarying string that needs to be replaced ("large"). All we need to do is this:

```
>> re.sub(r'large', r'hello', r'BoxUsage:c4.8xlarge')
>> 'BoxUsage:c4.8xhello'
```